# Why is server maintenance scheduled at mid-day European time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, server-maintenance

Looking at all the countries in this year's developer survey, the majority of users seems to be located in Europe. Counting all countries consisting of more than >1% of the survey participants, I get:

- Europe, 32% (including Russia and Turkey)
- Americas, 25%
- Others, 13% (India, Australia, Israel, Iran)

Counting those < 1% makes this even more in favour of the European/African time zone over Americas. Also notably, the Middle East is just a few hours ahead of Europe.

**Therefore, I wonder why maintenance is always scheduled at mid day, European time?**

Or if you will, early morning US (I believe 6am EST or such?). Wouldn't it make more sense to pick a time where as few users as possible are disrupted? Such as early morning EU/late evening US.

Alternatively, in case live humans need to be present during updates, wouldn't it make more sense to place maintenance during US office hours? Since the servers are located in USA. Then it would disrupt somewhat less people than it currently does and you also wouldn't have to pay overtime.

Just my €0.02

Comment: IST (India) is at UTC+5:30, which means in summer it's only 3.5 hours ahead of most of Europe (on CEST at UTC+2). Israel and Iran are both closer. Anything happening at 12:00 in UTC+1 or UTC+2 disturbs all of Europe and Africa, and half of Asia

Comment: I recognise my Northern Hemispherical bias by writing "summer", but it's too late to edit the comment and it will actually be summer for the majority of readers.

Comment: In the US it's pretty common to see deployments happening overnight for some reason. I've seen this at a variety of companies (especially multinational ones). Also I highly doubt anyone is getting paid overtime, they're almost certainly salaried.

Comment: @vandench Those multinational companies might have most of their user base in the Americas. Until today I thought that was also true for SO, but the survey says otherwise. Maybe SO management is having the same delusions as I had, hence this post. Any sensible company which gets most of their profit from online activity ought to avoid blocking users from using their product, not sub-optimise their maintenance so that it blocks _as many users as possible_.

Comment: Whose server maintenance? I'm kinda confused. I don't think we usually do it in the morning? - https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=planned%20maintenance While we occasionally have in the past, the most recent ones are either around midnight UTC or on weekends.

Comment: @Catija The server maintenance of this site (and the rest of SE). This whole week, at various times between roughly 10am to 2pm UTC I've been getting sporadic lag from all SE sites, sometimes refusing to load at all, and a lot of messages saying that the site is down for maintenance. I would assume SO claims the site is down for maintenance because it is down for maintenance, but I guess I shouldn't draw such conclusions?

Comment: OK... *that* is much more helpful to have in the question. As far as I'm aware, we post those MSE posts when we're doing big server maintenance, so I don't know what's causing the issues you're having. Can you please talk about your specific issues in the question rather than asking... this?

Comment: @Catija It's been like that sporadically for as long as I can remember. It doesn't happen often at all, once per month at most usually. Hence I had reason to believe that the cause was actual scheduled server maintenance, since that was also what the site told me. If the real cause is wild beavers in the server room or such, well I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Lundin that looks like [the ongoing DDoS attacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379561/testing-new-traffic-management-tool?cb=1#comment1266855_379561) rather than maintenance, I believe.

Comment: @Lundin That is the default message that is displayed when the site goes down or fails to respond for any reason. It doesn't necessarily mean it was scheduled.

Comment: If only there was a website that could tell us the state of play for the websites... Unfortunately, for me, [StackStatus](//stackstatus.net) has been down since it's launch... I find it somewhat ironic that the website that is meant to tell us if the website is having problems has been having problems since it's launch.

Comment: @Larnu you have to go to https://www.stackstatus.net/.  https://stackstatus.net/ appears to be broken.

Comment: ...I could fix the parsing of that comment with Markdown, but I'm going to leave it, because that's just silly.  Rest assured those are two *different* links, pasted into a comment with no additional formatting.

Comment: When I read that in my inbox I was so confused, @RyanM . I took me a "hot second" to realise the first has `www.` at the start. Thanks.

Comment: [Some sample scheduled times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=maintenance+time). E.g., page search for "planned" (case insensitive). (Far from all of them are tagged with "site-maintenance" or "maintenance".)

Comment: I think it's their new HTTP management service causing the lag, not server maintenance.

Comment: Just happened right now: "*We are currently offline for maintenance

Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will tweet updates from @StackStatus or post details on the [status blog](http://stackstatus.net/).*"

Comment: This is part of the decisive, 18th, package of the Western sanctions aimed at hurting the Russian military software development, which is done by copypasta from Stack Overflow. Eat this, Putin!

Comment: Pedantic note: 32% is not a majority, but it is a plurality.

Comment: One other thing to note: We strive very much to not need to take the site offline when performing maintenance.  We run redundant servers at pretty much every layer so that one can be taken out of the pool, maintained, put back in for service, then the next taken out, etc, without interrupting services. Even then, we will often go into read-only mode instead of going offline. It is only for major changes where we can't rely on redundancy that we will _intentionally_ take the site(s) offline. Bugs and attacks don't follow that rule, however.

Comment: Actually, [most registered users are from India](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1609963/users-at-location).

Answer (score 27):

As [animuson (a staff member) wrote in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418869/why-is-server-maintenance-scheduled-at-mid-day-european-time#comment916020_418869):

> That is the default message that is displayed when the site goes down or fails to respond for any reason. It doesn't necessarily mean it was scheduled.

Unfortunately, that default message...

> We are currently offline for maintenance
>
> Routine maintenance usually takes less than an hour. If this turns into an extended outage, we will tweet updates from @StackStatus or post details on the [status blog](http://stackstatus.net/).

<sup>(copied from [chivracq's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418869/why-is-server-maintenance-scheduled-at-mid-day-european-time#comment916082_418869))</sup>

...is not always correct. To avoid such misunderstandings in the future, my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) would be to replace that message with a more honest one, explaining that the site is currently unreachable and that this *might* be due to maintenance.

Comment: How about _different_ messages for planned maintenance and unexpected outages?

Comment: @Lundin: That would be ideal, of course, but that also means more work for the people doing the maintenance work. Thus, I thought I'd keep my feature request as simple as possible, to increase the chances of it being implemented.

Comment: Hey Heinzi, this Q&A was linked from [an answer on MSE to "Recent site instability, major outages – July/August 2022"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381183/241919). I noticed your remark about feature request, and I also thought the same. Do you want to post a feature request for this specifically?

Comment: @AndrewT.: Thanks for notifying my about that other answer! Well, we have my answer here and that other answer over there, so the StackOverflow team is aware of this feature request. I don't see how adding a third Q&A about this would improve the situation. If they want to fix it, they already know that the community wants it, and if they don't, adding another post from the same people won't change their mind. But if you want to try, be my guest, you'll have at least my upvote! :-)